# Построить контекстно-свободную грамматику, порождающую указанный язык

Tags: математика, дискретная-математика

Построить кс грамматику порождающую язык: a^n b^3m a^5 b^3 c^2n c^m n>0 m>0:n>0 m>0 более точно написано на скриншоте

Я построил вот так не знаю правильно ли это?

```
S->ABCDKM
A->a
B->bbb
C->aaaaa
D->bbb
K->cc
M->c
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все, что порождает ваша грамматика - это единственное слово `abbbaaaaabbbccc`...

Comment: почему? ведь можно для множества построить цепей https://sun9-38.userapi.com/c856028/v856028170/e5faf/Z9g2FOHKkt0.jpg

Comment: Потому что все, чем вы можете заменить нетерминал A - это единственный терминал a (и так далее) - у вас в описании грамматики имеются только однозначные подстановки. В примере по ссылке правила - и с нетерминалами справа, и с выбором вариантов (не знаю, как там это называется в формальной теории). Здесь в вопросе у вас ничего этого нет.